# How to construct query for getting value from mongo by matching the typed value in text box(like autocomplete)?

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having test collection in mongodb, In that collection i am having many documents in same structure as below,

```
       { "_id" : ObjectId("5026176dcac010a752b0d3a9"), 
         "number" : "yes",
         "url" :"www.emesene.com"
       }
```

Actually,I am creating auto-complete option for **"number"** and **"url"** fields in html, I have taken typed value , fields etc to backend..Now, I want to construct **basicdbobject** query using typedvalue and fields for getting stored values(as autocomplete) as based on the typed value.

I have constructed basicdbobject query as below but its not working

```
      query={ "url" : { "$regex" : "www" , "$options" : "i"} }
      collection.find(query).limit(5)

      field=url
      typed value=www
```

Anyone help me...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it with all its simplicity?

```
query={ url:{ "$regex" : "www" } }
collection.find(query).limit(5)
```

Comment: i'm not quite certain, imo this should work aswell: query={ url:{ $regex : "www", $options: 'i'} } collection.find(query).limit(5) The i flag is only for case sensitivity